# Uniform lower bound on convex functions bounded in $L^2$ norm

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, lp-spaces

Consider a class of (proper closed) convex function on $[0,1]^d$, which we shall denote $\mathcal{F}$. If every element of $\mathcal{F}$ is bounded in $L_2$, say
$$\int_{[0,1]^d} |f(x)|^2\ dx\leq 1,$$
then can we say something about the uniform lower bound of $\mathcal{F}$?

#### Progress

I proved the existence of a lower bound by contradiction but did not get an explicit bound.

Apparently we cannot expect a uniform upper bound.

Comment: Yes, there is a uniform lower bound on $f$. The set $U=\{x: f(x)<2\}$ is a convex set of some measure $\alpha$ which you can uniformly estimate from below. If $f(x_0)=-M$ for some large $M$, then on the set $\frac12x_0+\frac12U$ we have $f(x)<1-M/2$. This set has measure $\alpha/2^n$, so $|M/2-1|^2 \alpha/2^n \le 1$.

Comment: @Raff so it seems necessary to argue $x_0/2+U/2$ in included in the hypercube?

Comment: It is, because the cube is convex.

Comment: @Raff I see! Thanks very much for the explicit bound! I did it by contradiction but did not get the explicit bound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $U=\{x: f(x)\le 2\}$. This is a convex set. On the complement of $U$ we have $|f|^2> 4$, hence $|U^c|\le 1/4$ (writing $|\cdot|$ for the Lebesgue measure). This gives $|U|\ge 3/4$.

Suppose $f(x_0)=-M$ for some $x_0$, where $M>2$. The set $V = \frac12x_0+\frac12U$ is contained in $[0,1]^d$ and has measure at least $3\cdot 2^{-d-2}$. By convexity, $f<1-M/2$ on $V$, hence 
$$
 \int_{[0,1]^n}|f|^2 \ge (M/2-1)^2 |V| \ge 3(M-2)^2 2^{-d-4}
$$
Consequently, $M\le 2 + \sqrt{3}\cdot 2^{d/2+2}$ which means $\inf f\ge -2- \sqrt{3}\cdot 2^{d/2+2}$.